# Matrix from column

Tags: fortran, fortran90

The following data is given in a file:

> 1  7  5  4  11  0  1  -13  -7

I want to form a 3x3 matrix from these columns. I have tried `advance=no` but receive a runtime error.

```
program form_matrix
  implicit none
  integer:: col,A(9)
  open(unit=12,file='q10.txt')

  do col=1,9
    read(12,*,advance='no')(A(col))
  end do

  7 format(3i4)
  write(*,7)(A(col),col=1,9)
  close(12)
end program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a couple of things:

- To read into a variable, you need to specify that variable and not a statement containing the variable. `A(col)` instead of `(A(col))`.
- Then, you are not allowed to use the list directed format (`*`) with an `advance` specifier, you need a format (which would be difficult in your case, because of the different widths of the columns).
- It will probably be easier to read the whole line into the array in one go, without the loop and using the list directed format:

```
program form_matrix
  implicit none
  integer:: col,A(9)
  open(unit=12,file='q10.txt')

  read(12,*) A

  7 format(3i4)
  write(*,7)(A(col),col=1,9)
  close(12)
end program
```

`*` enables list-directed formatting, where individual values are separated by commas or blanks. The type is determined by the RHS of the statement. So you read in a list of nine (because `A` is nine elements long) integers (because `A` is integer). For more details on this I suggest the [Fortran 2008 Standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), Cl. 10.10 "List-directed formatting"

Comment: Can you please explain the line read(12,*) A. I mean I have always used array inside loop to read variable, how does it actually work only declaring the variable A?

Comment: `read(12,*)A` simply says to read enough values to fill the array.  Note that `A` can be dimensioned `A(3,3)` and the same simple read syntax will work.